# rails javascript json parse error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsing

I am working under rails 3.1.13, and if I add <%= javascript_include_tag :application %> in layout file, my web site can't work, and throw exception as below:

```
JSON::ParserError in Auto_test_sets#index

Showing E:/site/bqsysinfo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

*757: unexpected token at 'The node identifier for myserver is qe7sajt2h.
'
  (in E:/site/bqsysinfo/app/assets/javascripts/auto_test_sets.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):
3: <head>
4:   <title>my site</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">*
```

if I commont out this <%= javascript_include_tag :application %> it could work, but can't submit destroy request. any one can help?

Comment: Well, what does the JSON look like?

Comment: actually no any JSON I use. even I set up a new site, it can't work if I add <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>, will show JSON PARSE ERROR.....

Comment: `E:/site/bqsysinfo/app/assets/javascripts/auto_test_sets.js.coffee` seems to be causing the problem. Can you paste the contents of this file?

Comment: in auto_test_sets.js.cofee, there are only 3 lines:
    # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching      controller here.
    # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
    # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Answer (score 0):

Use coffee script online debugger: http://coffeescript.org/

Click "Try CoffeeScript" and paste your code of auto_test_sets.js.coffee. I think there's some bug in it so that the page is down.